# How to select tracked changes that are insertions in a Word table and copy it to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am working with Word documents that are simple tables. All of the information in the Word document is in a table. Some are hundreds of pages long, and are revised regularly.

Using Excel VBA, I am trying to open the Word document and copy to Excel only those rows from the table that are insertions.

I cobbled together code that will open the Word document and copy any tracked changes in the proper columns.

How do I limit it to insertions?

```vb
    'declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WordFilename As Variant
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim tbNo As Long
    Dim RowOutputNo As Long
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim ColNo As Integer
    Dim tbBegin As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Analysis")
    Filter = "Word File New (*.docx), *.docx," & _
    "Word File Old (*.doc), *.doc,"
    'clear all of the content in the worksheet where the tables from the Word document are to be imported
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    'if you only want to clear a specific range, replace .Cells with the range that you want to clear
    'displays a Browser that allows you to select the Word document that contains the table(s) to be imported into Excel
    WordFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , "Select Word file")
    If WordFilename = False Then Exit Sub
    'open the selected Word document
    Set WordDoc = GetObject(WordFilename)
    
    With WordDoc
    
    tbNo = WordDoc.Tables.Count
    
    If tbNo = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This document contains no tables"
    End If
    
    'nominate which row to begin inserting the data from. In this example we are inserting the data from row 1
    RowOutputNo = 1
    
    'go through each of the tables in the Word document and insert the data from each of the cells into Excel
    For tbBegin = 1 To tbNo
    With .Tables(tbBegin)
    For RowNo = 1 To .rows.Count
    For ColNo = 1 To .Columns.Count
    
    '-----This code works to only select revisions ----------------
    '-----Next step - make it only select insertions - 
    ' OR - let it mark what kind of revision it is-----
    
                Set rng = .Cell(RowNo, ColNo).Range
                'don't include the "end of cell" marker in the checked range
                'rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                numRevs = rng.Revisions.Count
                               
                If numRevs > 0 Then

    ws.Cells(RowOutputNo, ColNo) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(RowNo, ColNo).Range.Text)
    End If
    
    Next ColNo
    RowOutputNo = RowOutputNo + 1
    
    Next RowNo
    
    End With
    RowOutputNo = RowOutputNo
    
    Next tbBegin
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you use the object browser, or IntelliSense, or look up [the online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.revision.type)?

Comment: I have been using the online documentation.  My initial steps were to determine if each cell contained a revision, and if so, then try an if .Type to choose, but I have run into problems in assigning the range to .type I'm having trouble grasping how the disparate elements work together.  Intellisense has not yielded any particularly useful information as it seems to get confused as much as I do as I attempt to string this together.  I had not tried to view anything in the object browser, but in opening the initial document in Word2010, the object browser displays revisions very... strangely.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
If numRevs > 0 Then
    For revIdx = 1 To numRevs
        If Rng.Revisions(revIdx).Type = 1 Then
            'it's an insert
        End If
    Next revIdx
```